# How to display Youtube videos in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, youtube

I know that I can just start an intent with the URL, but I want a thumbnail that starts the video.

Just like here:
[image: Thumbnails]

How can I do this?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Well, I tried to put this inside a VideoView, but didn't work. I also saw that I can use the Youtube API. But if there is a way to do without using it, I'll prefer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use YouTube Android Player API. See instructions there: https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/

If you want open youtube channel by `Intent` you can use folowing snippet:

```
public static void watchYoutubeVideo(Context context, String channelId) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/channel/" + channelId));
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```